# $f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}g(s)\sin(\alpha(x-s))ds$, then $f^{\prime}(x)$ = 0?

Tags: calculus

$g$ is continuous and let

$$
f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}g(s)\sin(\alpha(x-s))ds
$$
I would like to know $f^{\prime}(x)$.

I could say using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that
$$
f^{\prime}(x) = g(s)\sin(\alpha(x-x)) = 0 ?
$$

Comment: Why $g(s)$ and not $g(x)$?

Comment: no because you have to differentiate the term inside the integral too so the derivative would be $f(x) = \alpha\int_{0}^{x}g(s)\cos(\alpha(x-s))ds$

Comment: @QC_QAOA it's g(s) same

Comment: Use Leibnitz rule for differentiation under the integral 

https://brilliant.org/wiki/differentiate-through-the-integral/

Comment: @Conrad Why is the derivative the integral of the integrand?

Comment: @DeeponjitBose Thank you

Comment: the derivative is obtained by applying the Leibniz rule, so you get an extra term from differentiating inside the integral wr $x$ and that gives you $\alpha\int_{0}^{x}g(s)\cos(\alpha(x-s))ds$ which is not the original integrand - if you want to convince yourself write (by expanding the inside $\sin$) that $f(x)=a(x)b(x)+c(x)d(x)$ where $a(x)=\sin (\alpha x), b(x)=\int_{0}^{x}g(s)\cos(\alpha s)ds$ etc, apply the usual product rule beacuse now the integral differentiate indeed directly and then bring back the stuff inside

Comment: @CarinSa So is your problem solved

Comment: @Conrad  If $b(x) = \int_{0}^{x}g(s)\cos(\alpha s)ds$. Then $b^{\prime}(x) = g(x)cos(\alpha x)$?

Comment: yes correct - so you get that $f'(x)=\alpha \cos \alpha (x) \int_{0}^{x}g(s)\cos(\alpha s)ds+\sin \alpha (x) g(x)cos(\alpha x)+\alpha \sin \alpha (x) \int_{0}^{x}g(s)\sin(\alpha s)ds-\cos\alpha (x) g(x)sin(\alpha x)$ which simplifies to $\alpha\int_{0}^{x}g(s)\cos(\alpha (x-s))ds$ which again you can see directly by differentiating correctly the original integral

Comment: @Conrad Thank Very much.